# how to make php' curl output all http requests (not only last) in case of redirect(s)?

Tags: php, curl, header, request, request-headers

Problem is that I can't get all sequential request headers with php curl.
Curl returns **only last request' headers**.
Please check php code below:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://yandex.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //include the header in the output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); //track the handle's request str
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //seconds

$requestHeaders = array("Connection: keep-alive", //we want to look like real browser
    "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36",
    "Dnt: 1",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4,tr;q=0.2"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

echo 'Redirect count = ' . $info['redirect_count'] . "\n\n<br /><br />";
echo "Request header\n<br />" . str_replace("\n", "\n<br />", $info['request_header']) . "\n\n<br /><br />";
echo "Response headers\n<br />" . str_replace("\n", "\n<br />", substr($response, 0, intval($info['header_size']))) . "\n\n<br /><br />";
```

This code shows only last request headers:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yandex.com
Cookie: yandexuid=1858417061425447211
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Dnt: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4,tr;q=0.2
```

But all three http responses:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.yandex.com/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:31 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Location: https://www.yandex.com/
Expires: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:31 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:31 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP ADM DEV PSD IVDo OUR IND STP PHY PRE NAV UNI"
Set-Cookie: yandexuid=1858417061425447211; Expires=Sat, 01-Mar-2025 05:33:31 GMT; Domain=.yandex.com; Path=/
X-XRDS-Location: http://openid.yandex.ru/server_xrds/

HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Expires: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:32 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:33:32 GMT
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' wss://portal-xiva.yandex.net *.yandex.ru yandex.ru *.yandex.net *.yandex.com yandex.com yandex.st yastatic.net *.yastatic.net wss://portal-xiva.yandex.net wss://push.yandex.ru; img-src data: 'self' *.yandex.ru *.yandex.com *.tns-counter.ru *.gemius.pl yandex.st *.yandex.net yastatic.net *.yastatic.net; report-uri https://www.yandex.ru/log/csp?from=com.com&showid=22877.12428.1425447211.60001&h=m60&yu=1858417061425447211;
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP ADM DEV PSD IVDo OUR IND STP PHY PRE NAV UNI"
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XRDS-Location: http://openid.yandex.ru/server_xrds/
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Checked on

- win8.1, php5.5.9 x86, apache x86, curl 7.30.0
- Linux 2.6.32, PHP 5.4.32, curl 7.19.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do so by cURL means. The only way is handle redirects **manually**.
Something like this:

```
$a_options = array(
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        ...
    ),
);
$a_headers = array();
$url = 'http://yandex.com';
$url_ref = '';
$ch = curl_init();
$count = 0;
for ($count = 0; $url; $count++) {
    $a_options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;
    if ($url_ref) $a_options[CURLOPT_REFERER] = $url_ref;
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $a_options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $a_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $i = $a_info['header_size']);
    $response = substr($response, $i);
    $a_headers[] = array(
        'request' => $a_info['request_header'],
        'response' => $header
    );
    $url_ref = $url;
    $url = '';
    if ($a_info['http_code'] == 302 && 
        preg_match('/\nlocation:\s*(\S+)\s/i', $header, $arr)) {
        $url = $arr[1];
    }
}

echo "Redirect count = $count\n\n";
echo "Headers:\n" . print_r($a_headers, true) . "\n\n";
```

Comment: I was thinking about manual processing of redirects and catching requests, but I hoped it's possible with curl itself. Thanx for the response and code sample.

Comment: @dtmax1 Frankly I can't imagine why would you need request headers for the example above. The only case I can imagine is learn the exact content of data sent with a POST request as well as related info (such as content-type). Although most of CURL builds don't allow to learn body (data) of a POST request, only its size.

Comment: It's for simple http-protocol monitoring tool, similar to 'Network' tab in Firefox/Chrome, but with server side also.